# PHP (CakePHP) - Recognizing created form elements by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp

I'm working on a CakePHP application. In my application, pages have a form tag with not elements inside. The form elements (inputs and etc) are created dynamically with JavaScript. So after some certain event, I create the needed elements and append them to the parent node. The result is a form which contains the elements.

```
for (var i = 0; i < targets.length ; i++) {
        var edt = document.createElement("input");
        edt.setAttribute("type","text");
        edt.setAttribute("id","edt_"+targets[i].id);
        edt.setAttribute("name","edt_"+targets[i].id);
        targets[i].innerHTML = "";
        targets[i].appendChild(edt);
        //Pushing newly created obj to array
        objs.push(edt);
    }
```

CakePHP cannot processes the newly created elements using this:

```
$global_1_user = $this->request->data['edt_1_user'];
$this->set('global_1_user',$global_1_user);
```

However, if I don't create the elements dynamically and have them in my HTML code, the CakePHP can recognize the elements just fine. Anyone can help me with this? Why is this happening? and how can I overcome this issue? Any alternative ways to achieve this?

Comment: It's most likely the security component blocking access to these variables. It can be quite selective over what it allows you to transfer through the app and can sometimes block variables simply because the HTML tag might have a syntax error in it. I suggest you just use regular old `$_POST` or `$_GET` to access these as a work around

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding how PHP and JavaScript work. The PHP code can never "see" the results of the JavaScript code (including jQuery), because PHP runs on the server, while JavaScript runs in the browser. By the time the JavaScript starts running, the server is done with the PHP.

If you really need to use PHP to do something after the JavaScript has already run, you can do that with AJAX.

Comment: I know what you're saying ... it's not that. When I use:
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).serialize());
    //alert();
});
to check the values being sent, the console doesn't show any of the inputs. The problem is with objs.push(edt);. I have an array which I store the objects into it and at the end of the function i return the object. Pushing the elements in the array removes them from the FORM node (not physically thou). So if I comment out that line, things will be fine ... but why?!

Comment: I'm not sure why commenting out `objs.push(edt);` improves things. The other possibilities that stand out to me are these: (1) `targets[i].id` should be a digit plus "_user", like `1_user`; verify this using `console.log`. (2) Maybe `objs` isn't what you think it is; try `console.log(objs);` to verify that it is what you expect. (3) Is the new input being attached to your `form` element? If not, that would explain why the submit fails. It's hard to tell from the code above whether you ever attach it in the DOM.

Comment: Elements:
<input type=​"text" name=​"edt_1_user">​
<input type=​"text" name=​"edt_2_user">​
<input type=​"text" name=​"edt_3_user">​
<input type=​"text" name=​"edt_more_user">​
Objs: [input, input, input, input]
The objs at this point is simply a an array of objects(elements). Later I use this to remove the inserted elements from DOM. I'll try pushing IDs (as string) into the array and use the ID (string) later to remove them instead of the object itself...

Answer (score 0):

The problem for some reason has to do with:

```
objs.push(edt);
```

if I don't push the elements (simply comment out the line), then it works fine. Anyone knows the technical reason behind this?